# The relationship between RGMII to MDI in Ethernet communication

Tags: ethernet, raw-ethernet

Let's say I am talking to a PHY chip via RGMII.

What is the relationship between the serial information transmitted on the RGMII to the signals that go out to the MDI?

I understood from the timing diagram of RGMII that the rising edge is 4 bits and the falling edge is 4 bits. So for each clock that gives 8 bits.

For 100Mbps, the clock required is 25MHz. So for every 25MHz clock cycle, 8 bits are transmitted.

Does the PHY chip simply send each 8 bits over the MDI immediately?

If that is the case, then how do I correctly package these serial 8 bits of data into a proper ethernet frame?

I a trying to troubleshoot a piece of hardware where the PHY does not work properly but the only way troubleshoot is if I can control the RGMII. However, I do not understand this relationship between the RGMII and how it affects the MDI.

I presume that if I look at wireshark, it will not show any packets of information unless I send a string of serialized data in a proper Ethernet frame.

Comment: This might be more suitable for [electronics.SE] given that more users there have experience with hardware and protocols such as XGMII. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to auto-migrate the question from here so you'll probably need to re-ask there if you don't get responses here.

Answer (score 0):

The PHY should have some documentation and sample code. Without, finding out how exactly it works can be a very tedious task.

You can find the general RGMII description here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160303212629/http://www.hp.com/rnd/pdfs/RGMIIv1_3.pdf